# How to check if objectB used instance of objectA from objectA using private variables

Tags: php, oop

**Code Explanation**

I have two classes, mesh and geometry, that are used to maintain attributes of a 3D array to fill a space. First a mesh is defined and builds a 3D array. Then geometric shapes can be created within the same bounds of the mesh object, but not in the original mesh object. This is done by passing the mesh in to the shape so that it uses the bounds of the mesh.

The shape has functions that are not shown below to fill in cells as needed. For example, you could add a sphere centered at a point with a specified radius and the shape will work out which cells to fill in. Then say I really wanted a hemisphere, I could clear out everything below the center of the sphere and I would have an array that when translated to 3D space would draw a (pixelated) hemisphere.

There are properties that allow the mesh and geometry to work out a physical spatial location which have been removed in the code below since they are not relevant.

Once a shape has reached its final form, I want to be able to merge it back into the original mesh. So, if I wanted to create a silo, I would create a hemisphere object as described above, then a cylinder, and then add both back into the original mesh.

**Problem Statement**

I want to make sure that the geometry object used the mesh that it is being added to.

```
$mesh1 = new mesh(2,2,2);
$mesh2 = new mesh(2,2,2);

$geo = new geometry($mesh1);
$geo->fill(0,0,0,1);
$geo->fill(1,1,1,1);

$mesh1->add($geo); //should be fine;
$mesh2->add($geo); //should do nothing since $geo used $mesh1 and not $mesh2
```

I know I can use the `===` operator on the objects to make sure they are the same,

```
if ($this === $geo->mesh)
```

but it doesn't work of the `$geo->mesh` is private. I would prefer to keep the mesh private if possible. Making `$geo->mesh` public solves the issue, but does not protect `$geo->mesh` as well as I would like.

I considered maybe naming the mesh and making it a public geometry variable, but it's not as clean as I would like.

```
public $name; //in mesh object
public $mesh_name; //in geometry object
$this->mesh_name = $mesh->name; //in geometry constructor

if ($this->name == $geo->mesh_name)
...
```

Is there a way to check that the mesh the geometry used is the same mesh without breaking encapsulation or requiring inheritance?

**Code for the classes**

```
class mesh
{
    private $domain;

    public $i;
    public $j;
    public $k;

    public function __construct($i, $j, $k)
    {
        $this->i = $i;
        $this->j = $j;
        $this->k = $k;
        $this->build();
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $karr = array_fill(0, $this->k, 0);
        $jarr = array_fill(0, $this->j, $karr);
        $this->domain = array_fill(0, $this->i, $jarr);
    }

    public function add(geometry $geo)
    {
        // if ($this === $geo->mesh)
        {

            for ($i = 0; $i < $this->i; $i++){
                for ($j = 0; $j < $this->j; $j++){
                    for ($k = 0; $k < $this->k; $k++){

                        if ($geo->domain[$i][$j][$k] > 0)
                            $this->domain[$i][$j][$k] = $geo->domain[$i][$j][$k]; 

    }   }   }   }   }

}

class geometry
{
    private $mesh; //would rather keep private

    public $domain;

    public function __construct(mesh $mesh)
    {
        $this->mesh = $mesh;
        $this->build();
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $karr = array_fill(0, $this->mesh->k, 0);
        $jarr = array_fill(0, $this->mesh->j, $karr);
        $this->domain = array_fill(0, $this->mesh->i, $jarr);
    }

    public function fill($i, $j, $k, $value)
    {
        $this->domain[$i][$j][$k] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Getters and Setters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get). The below code will let the `$mesh_name` property be read, but not written by external code.

```
class MyObject {
    protected $mesh_name = 'foo';
    protected $accessible = ['mesh_name'];
    protected $writable = [];
    
    public function __get($name) {
        if( in_array($name, $this->accessible) ) [
            return $this->name;
        } else {
            // return null, throw exception, do nothing
        }
    }
    
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if( in_array($name, $this->writable) ) {
            if( $this->validationMethod($value) ) {
                $this->$name = $value;
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Property $name failed validation: $value");
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Property $name is not marked as writable.");
        }
    }
}
```

eg:

```
$foo = new MyObject();
echo $foo->mesh_name; // foo
$foo->mesh_name = 'bar'; // Exception("Property mesh_name is not marked as writable.");
```

Comment: Should have thought about `__get`. My understanding is  that `__get` is only used for private/protected variables, so this works for what I was trying to do and prevents unwanted manipulation, but now I'm wondering if there's a way to control what can access `__get`. For example, make it so only a mesh object can read the geometry mesh variable.

Comment: @pyriccrash not really, but you're treating these code objects as though they have a will of their own and will attempt to misbehave if given a chance. This is code, it will only do what you tell it to do.